# React children rerender

Tags: reactjs, parent, composition, children, rerender

I have two layouts one for mobile second for desktop view. Thier structure is different however both inject the same childrens. I would like to prevent childrens rerender when the layout switch. Here is pseudocode which reflect the case(or check live https://playcode.io/1193034):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


interface ParentProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Parent = ({ children }: ParentProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(false);

  if (value) {
    return (
      <>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setValue((val) => !val)}>
          Turn into false
        </button>
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    // some additional elements for desktop view
    <div> 
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setValue((val) => !val)}>
          Turn into true
        </button>
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const ChildrenComponent = () => {
  console.log("rerender Children...");
  return <p>children component</p>;
};

export const App = ()=> {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <ChildrenComponent />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

What could I do?

So far I have tried to wrap children component in Rect.memo and useMemo (inside Parent) both didn't work. Maybe it's just impossible to do

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to avoid rerendering in your scenario, as you are rendering different elements in different positions

The way React knows what elements to rerender is by creating a tree structure (the virtual DOM) and comparing it to the browser DOM. When a node in the virtual DOM changes in relation to the browser DOM, it will be replaced (and therefore rerendered), along with every child element of this node. This process is called [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

Because of this, even if some of the child components are the same, once you change the position or the type of their parent elements, there is no way to avoid their rerendering.

---

On a sidenote, you could avoid the rerendering if you restructure your component to always return the same types of elements in the same positions, and make them responsive by using [CSS media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp).

Comment: Yes, you are right. I could workaround that with conditional css, in the end final Parent will be quite ugly,complicated and for mobile wrapped with some additonal 'empty' divs but won't rerender children. I hoped that there is any other solution ;)

Comment: This is the only solution I'm aware of, given React limitations. Usually it's not too ugly, if you plan the structure ahead.